# How to include config file in multiple directories php pages

Tags: php, directory-structure

I have a following directory structure for my project in which I have `Init.php` file under `core` folder. I wanted to include this file on every pages under the `views` folder to auto load all my classes defined under `classes` folder. But when I am including `require_once '../../core/Init.php';` from a sub-directory of `views` folder it gives me following error

> require_once(classes/Config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Including this file in every pages under the `views` folder

```
require_once 'core/Init.php';
```

core/Init.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {    
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

My directory structure is as below

[image: Directory Structure]

I would like to include this single file (`core/Init.php`) into all my files, directories and sub-directories of views folder. Any one have an idea how would I do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is that your code actually gets executed from multiple directories.

Instead it should be called through a single point of entry (usually referred to as "bootstrap file").

Basically, you do something like this.

```
$config = require __DIR__ '/../config.php';
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? 'home';

if (in_array($page, $whitelist)) {
    require __DIR__ . "/path/to/pages/{$page}.php";
}
```

Oh, and don't refer to your template as "views". They are not.

Answer (score 0):

Structure! When starting the application tell it where to find things then add the spl_autoload_register function and setup the things which are always accessible:

```
.../www/index.php
eg (in index.php):
chdir(__DIR__):
```

Now every thing starts at .../www/ directory. From that point you can start to setup all paths you wish to include. Relative or absolute.

Kind regards